# Import csv to sql bash

Tags: mysql, sql, bash, csv, zsh

I am trying to write a bash script to drop all tables in a database then import all csv files in a given directory. I am having a couple of issues though:

1. Importing 1 csv with the script gives the following error:

   ```
   ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 2: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BULK
   INSERT paf_addresses
   FROM '../sql/paf-sample.csv'
   WITH
   (
   FIELDTERMINATOR = ' at line 1
   ```
2. How to tell the mysql part to run for every file in a set directory

---

My script is below.

```
#!/bin/bash

detail="propertystork"
AWK=$(which awk)
GREP=$(which grep)

TABLES=$(mysql -u $detail -p$detail $detail -e 'show tables' | $AWK '{ print $1}' | $GREP -v '^Tables' )

for t in $TABLES
do
  mysql -u $detail -p$detail $detail -e "drop table $t"
done

mysql -u $detail -p$detail -h localhost $detail <<-_END-OF-SCRIPT_

BULK
INSERT paf_addresses
FROM '../sql/paf-sample.csv'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO
_END-OF-SCRIPT_
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused by the fact that there is no `BULK INSERT` statement in MySQL.

Instead there is [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html)

```sql
LOAD DATA INFILE '../sql/paf-sample.csv'
INTO table_name
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Comment: I was working off [this](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/06/sql-server-import-csv-file-into-sql-server-using-bulk-insert-load-comma-delimited-file-into-sql-server/) blog post from 2008 which said there was, or have I misinterpreted it?

Comment: You're confused `BULK INSERT` is for **SQL Server** not for **MySQL** which are two completely different database management systems

Comment: Okay thanks for your help :) that solved problem 1. any ideas on part 2?

Comment: The logic of the script is wrong. If you drop tables you won't be able to load data from csv files. You'll have to create tables first. That would work only if you'd have sql dump files instead of cdv files.